# How to add roughness to a surface of a material with image texture?

Tags: node-editor, subdivision-surface, roughness

I want to use the node editor to give them each a different level of roughness

This is what I tried

[image]

I just want to make the surface rough. But I don't know how.

This is the final result that I want to have.

[image]

I need your help ;)

[image]

Comment: Plug the "normal" output of your bump node into the "normal" input of your shader ( instead of  "roughness") and see what happens ;)

Comment: I got rough surfaces but two faces are black

Comment: you need to put your image in the Height input of the Bump node, and plug the Bump into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF, have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Change the *Color Space* of the Grunge.jpg image texture to *Non-Color* (It's currently sRGB), and connect it to the Roughness input of the Principled BSDF (without the bump node). You can still use the image as a bump map as well, just don't connect the Bump Node to the roughness (only connect it to the normal). For either of these uses, the image still needs to be changed to "Non-Color":

[image: MineBlock]